# What filter should I pass to these signals to make them constant on every piece

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, frequency

I'm analysing the frequencies of something I'm recording (whistling), which is resulting like this (yes, it's super mario bros' beginning song:

[image]

I'd like to filter it to make it remain like:

[image]

in order to convert them as MIDI notes after the processing.

How could I do it ?

I've tried with a simple low-pass filter but it doesn't work very well.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm already rounding it when passing to MIDI:

[image]

and sometimes it goes on + - 1 note.

Comment: Oh, I'm implementing it in Java.

Comment: There's no such filter for the standard meaning of filter (as in, linear time invariant system), but you could start with rounding to the nearest note on the scale.

Comment: Wait, I'm going to edit it

Comment: A good start would be a voiced/unvoiced detector that allows you to create segments. Then you can use some form of predictive filtering to process the segments and decide if the pitch has changed. Divide into constant pitch segments again and find the average pitch for each.